# jquery .post elements created with append

Tags: php, jquery

I have a code with input field, and with clicking on add it adds new input field with new name:

```
/* multiply recepient */
var number = 1;
$('a.plus').live('click', function() {
    number += 1; 
    $('.multiple').append('<p><input type="text" name="recepient_' + number + '"></p>');
});
```

this works fine. But then I want to post entered values with $.post() and only the first input fileld is posted, the original one, all created with append are note posted... Here is my post function:

```
$('input.submit').live('click', function() {
    var postdata = $('form#form1').serialize(); 
    $.post('result.php', postdata, function(data) {
     $('div.result').html(data);
});   
return false;
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is the $.post send the right data to result.php? What does Firebug console tells? Maybe show us result.php to see if the problem doesn't come from here ;)

Comment: Is .multiple somewhere beneath #form1 in the DOM?

Comment: Where is the `.multiple` element? Is it inside the `#form1`? Is there more than one on the page? Can we see your HTML? When I do a simple test, all `input` elements are serialized, including ones that are appended. http://jsfiddle.net/s5hSu/

Comment: Hi,

1.) result.php is ok, I just output <?php print_r($_REQUEST) ?> and I see all other fields.

2.) .multiple is td field inside #form1.

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the error -  has to be outside of  .....

Comment: ok, found the error :/ <form> has to be outside of <table> and than it works.... Sorry!